# AJAX PHP net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am getting `abc.com/content/show.php net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED` from my website. It is the first time I am seeing this problem. I have searched some solution but they can not solve my problem.

```
$("body").on("click", ".notifHG", function() {
      var ID = $(this).attr("id");
      //doing AJAX request
    $.ajax({
      url:"/content/show.php",
      beforeSend:function(){
        $('#myDiv').fadeOut('slow');
      },
      success:function(response){
        $('.NotificatonListWrap').html(response);
      }
    });    

   });
```

**show.php**

```
<?php include_once '../functions/funcs.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Can you share the `funcs.php` code?

Comment: Or show the `show.php` also

Answer (score 4):

I found on Internet (thanks Google !), a possible answer for your issue.

This is a browser error ?

http://stefantsov.com/fixing-err_content_decoding_failed-in-apachephp/

If you have this error:

> ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED
>   Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED): Unknown error.

This error seems to be linked to the compression and uncompression of webpage. If you use `gz output`, or any compression on `ob_start()` function or automatic ones for php/apache module, you can get this issue ... for some apache version.

A possible fix, is to activate the correct module:

> Adding zlib.output_compression = On to php.ini.

Answer (score 2):

Just had this same issue, using CodeIgniter.

Solved by changing $config['compress_output'] to FALSE in application/config.php.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling output compression works on CodeIgniter...turning off this feature can increase the page load sleep however it is a safer option given that not all browsers support compression